# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, g++

I am trying to compile a C++ program that uses Armadillo C++ library for linear algebra & scientific computing. When I give command :
`g++ gen_data.cpp -o test -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER -lopenblas -llapack`

I am getting an error as follows:

```
In file included from /usr/include/armadillo:23,
                 from gen_data.cpp:7:
/usr/include/armadillo_bits/compiler_check.hpp:67:65: note: #pragma message: WARNING: option ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11 ignored
   67 |   #pragma message ("WARNING: option ARMA_DONT_USE_CXX11 ignored")
      |                                                                 ^
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Did you install the openblas development package(s)?